# How to retrieve image filename when inserting pictures to Word document

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have Word documents that contain some pictures.  The code to add the pictures is:
    `ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddPicture Anchor:= Selection.Range, fileName:=localFileName, LinkToFile:=True, SaveWithDocument:=True`

Is there anyway to come back to that picture and read the filename variable?  I can go through the Shapes collection of the ActiveDocument and check for pictures, but I don't see a property that would expose the localFileName.

Comment: Once embedded in the document, AFAIK and if I understand correctly, the image becomes an OLE object that's, well, *embedded* in the document; as such there is no "local file name", the image lives *in the document*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For images added to a Word document with the

`ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddPicture Anchor:= Selection.Range, fileName:=localFileName, LinkToFile:=True, SaveWithDocument:=True`

method, the link is available as

```
ShapeOfInterest.LinkFormat.SourceFullName
```

This is only valid if there is a link in the document.  You will know if this is the case by looking on the Info screen for the document where there will be an "Edit Links to Files" menu item under Related Documents.  For the case where a link goes missing (?), you will receive an empty image and [linked image cannot be displayed image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Y2pJ.png)

Normally, the link is still available, even if you get the error message.  In my document it was not.